# How to export a featureOverlay drawn on openlayers3 map (projection EPSG:3857) to a KML file projected to EPSG:4326

Tags: openlayers-3

I am drawing polygons on a featureOverlay attached to openlayers3 map (projection EPSG:3857) as follows:

```
// create openlayers3 map
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [-11000000, 4600000],
        zoom: 4
    })
});

// create the featureOverlay to receive polygons
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay();
featureOverlay.setMap(map);

// create the tool to draw polygons
draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
    type: 'Polygon'
});
map.addInteraction(draw);
```

Until here, everything is ok! The idea is from oficial [Draw features example](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/draw-features.html). The next step is to export features drawn on the map to a KML file using projection EPSG:4326. I have tried to reach this task through the following code:

```
$('#download-button').click(function() {
    // get the features drawn on the map
    var features = featureOverlay.getFeatures().getArray();
    // create an object to write features on a output KML file 
    var format = new ol.format.KML();
    // write features to KML format using projection EPSG:4326
    var kml = format.writeFeatures(features, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
    // Save KML node as KML file using FileSaver.js script
    var str = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(kml);
    var blob = new Blob([str], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;"});
    saveAs(blob, "NovaCamada.kml");
});
```

The main problem is KML file result always contains features with vertices on metrics units (I need degrees units!) even when shows the KML file on EPSG:4326.
The worst (and the purpose of my question) is that even when I change the piece of code that writes features to kml format to:

```
var kml = format.writeFeatures(features);
```

or:

```
var kml = format.writeFeatures(features, 'EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:4326');
```

the result is the same and nothing changes!

I expect ol.format.KML class converts the features from EPSG:3857 to EPSG:4326. Am I on the right way? 
Do I need apply any reprojection on features before format it? Someone please could help me with this task?

Did I make myself clear?

P.S.: [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writeFeatures` takes, as the 2nd argument, an object literal with two properties: `dataProjection` and `featureProjection`.

The KML format has a default `dataProjection`, EPSG:4326. This means you only need to specify the `featureProjection` in your case:

```js
var result = kmlFormat.writeFeatures(features, {featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});
```

Unrelated note: we are changing the return type of `writeFeatures` in OpenLayers 3.1.0. `writeFeatures` will always return a string, for any format. This means you won't need to serialize the result of `writeFeatures` yourself with `XMLSerializer`.